# Configuring RAID controller in Centos linux

Tags: linux, raid, dell

I have leased a dell poweredge r210 server, it's default configuration is CentOS 5.x as OS and a hardware RAID 1 controller configured. I want to configure my hardware RAID but can't seem to figure out where. So far I tried the following:

1. Rebooted the system to see if PERC can be accessed from the BIOS (but this option is not present)
2. Installed OMSA (but this tool couldn't identify my raid controller)

Your help is appreciated, I'm still new to system administration so sorry for the somehow obvious solution for some.

Comment: What model of RAID controller do you have?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Dell RAID controllers are not configured from the system BIOS but, rather, from their own firmware configuration screen. If memory and some Googling serves, then pressing "F2" gets you the regular BIOS and, ctrl+m (or maybe ctrl+r) will get you the perc BIOS. Within the Perc controller BIOS settings you can configure RAID groups.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Fred, turns out that this server is using SAS 6i/R controller which you can access using CTRL+C at boot and indeed it uses its own firmware config screen.